# Save image from picturebox default image (from resources)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

[image]

how to save this image
into sqlserver, i usually save it from file name but i don't know how to save from resources

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25956/Sending-Receiving-PictureBox-Image-in-C-To-From-Mi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public byte[] WinImage=new byte[0];
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
PictureBox.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
WinImage=stream.ToArray();
```

And save it to the table as `varbinary(max)`.
To open the image from database:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byte[] WinImage);
Image RetImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
PictureBox.Image = RetImage;
```

Comment: byte[] imageData =XXXX ReadFile();
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO KeyWord (ItemName, DateEntry,image, imageindex) VALUES (N'" + listBoxI.ToString() + "', GETDATE(), @image, 1)", cn);
    cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", (object)imageData);
    cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

Comment: Replace `(object)imageData` with `WinImage`. Image column should be of type `varbinary(max)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert image to filestream like this,

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
data = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
```

Then you can save the image as `byte[]` array to your database table where the field datatype is `Image`.